# Non-empty intersection of specific sets

Tags: general-topology, logic

For any set Y (to begin with, it may be countable), given a collection of relations 
     $$R =  \{R_y \subseteq \{0,1\}^Y \mid y \in Y\},$$ 
having the finite intersection property and such that for every $y\in Y$, every $a \in \{0,1\}^{Y\setminus\{y\}}$ can be completed by some (ordered) pair $\{y,v\}$ so that: $a \cup \{y,v\} \in R_y$. Is it the case  that $\bigcap R \not= \emptyset$ ?

When for each $R_y$, all $r\in R_y$ have only one value at $y$ (i.e., projections of all $r$ on $y$ are equal), then the intersection is non-empty by compactness, since R has FIP. But in general?

Answer (score 0):

If $Y=\emptyset$, $R=\emptyset$ and $\bigcap R$ is not defined. If $Y=\{y\}$ is a singleton then $R=R_y$ is not empty as it contains a completion of $\emptyset\in\{0,1\}^\emptyset$.
Hence we may assume $Y$ has at least two elements $y_1,y_2$.

Consider first the case of finite $Y$.
Let $$\tag1\begin{align}O&=\{\,f\colon Y\to\{0,1\}\mid \#f^{-1}(1)\text{ odd}\,\}\\E&=\{\,f\colon Y\to\{0,1\}\mid \#f^{-1}(1)\text{ even}\,\}.\end{align}$$
Then if $R_y=O$ or $R_y=E$ the completion property holds: Exactly one of the two possible completions of any given $a\in\{0,1\}^{Y\setminus\{y\}}$ is in $O$ and one is in $E$. Thus we can let $$\tag2R_y=\begin{cases}O&\text{if $y=y_1$}\\E&\text{if $y\ne y_1$}\end{cases} 
$$
and obtain 
$$ \bigcap R\subseteq R_{y_1}\cap R_{y_2}=O\cap E=\emptyset.$$

Next consider the case of arbitrary $Y$.
In order to redo the construction of above, we need to introduce a "parity" for subsets of $Y$, that is a map $p\colon \mathcal P(Y)\to\{-1,1\}$ such that we always have $$p(A\cup\{y\})\ne p(A\setminus\{y\})$$
or more generally 
$$ p(A\bigtriangleup B)=p(A)\cdot (-1)^{|B|}\quad\text{if $|B|<\infty$}\tag3$$
Let $\mathcal T$ be the set of *partial* parity maps on $Y$, that is maps $p\colon S\to\{-1,+1\}$ with $S\subseteq \mathcal P(Y)$ such that $(3)$ holds whenever both $A$ and $A\bigtriangleup B$ are $\in S$.
Then $\mathcal T$ is nonempty and is inductively ordered, hence by **Zorn's lemma** contains a maximal element $m\colon M\to\{-1,1\}$.

Assume $A\notin M$ for some $A\subseteq Y$. If for all finite sets $B$ with $A\bigtriangleup B\in M$ we have $m(A\bigtriangleup B)=(-1)^{|B|}$, then we can extend $m$ to $M\cup\{A\}$ by mapping $A\mapsto +1$, which contradicts maximality of $m$. Likewise, if for all finite sets $B$ with $A\bigtriangleup B\in M$ we have $m(A\bigtriangleup B)=-(-1)^{|B|}$, then we can extend $m$ to $M\cup\{A\}$ by mapping $A\mapsto -1$, again contradicting maximality.
We conclude that there are finite sets $B_-,B_+$ such that $A\bigtriangleup B_-,A\bigtriangleup B_+\in M$, $m(A\bigtriangleup B_-)=-(-1)^{|B_-|}$, $m(A\bigtriangleup B_+)=(-1)^{|B_+|}$. But then with $B:=B_+\bigtriangleup B_-$ and $A'=A\bigtriangleup B_-$ we have 
$$ m(A')=m(A\bigtriangleup B_-)=-(-1)^{|B_-|}$$
and
$$ m(A'\bigtriangleup B)=m(A\bigtriangleup B_+)=(-1)^{|B_+|}$$
which contradicts $(3)$ because $(-1)^{|B|}=(-1)^{|B_+|+|B_-|}$.
Therefore $m$ is defined on all of $\mathcal P(Y)$. Now we can replace $(1)$ with
$$\tag{1'}\begin{align}O&=\{\,f\colon Y\to\{0,1\}\mid m(f^{-1}(1))=-1\,\}\\E&=\{\,f\colon Y\to\{0,1\}\mid m(f^{-1}(1))=+1\,\}.\end{align}$$
The rest of the proof runs just the same and produces $R$ with $\bigcap R=\emptyset$.

Comment: What happened to the FIP (finite intersection property), which R also has?

Comment: In (1), $R_{y_2} \cap R_{y_1} = E \cap O = \emptyset$, so this R does not have FIP. The same seems to happen replacing (1) by (1'), but perhaps I am missing something in the argument?